# Series solution of an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This the question:

Consider $xy'+y = 0$ ,$y(1) = 1$ and try to develop a series solution to the equation in an approximate range and about an approximate center.

What does it mean by approximate range and approximate center?

Comment: Every power series has a center and radius of convegence

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(x-a)^n}$

Comment: Beware:  for  $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ , this is _no longer_ the same differential equation, so you should not "build" your solution around that point (this is a "singular" equation).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/750437)